# AS3 (Adobe AIR / Flash) gotoAndPlay causing immense lag, even though it's only being called once?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, air, flash-cs4

I am creating a game, in AS3, in Flash CS4, with Adobe AIR. The game has gotten too large and complex for me to share the full thing on here, but I will try to explain my problem.

The background of my game is animated water, and it is a symbol separate of the game character and the other entities in the game. When the character performs certain tasks, the water animation needs to jump to a certain frame. This should be really easy:

```
water_background.gotoAndPlay(the_frame);
```

However, this for some reason is causing a lot of lag, regardless of the machine I use it on. Right when the gotoAndPlay fires off, there is about a 700 millisecond delay where everything freezes up, and then when it comes out of it, all the animations already have completed and the water is playing from the appropriate frame, however the user misses all the pretty animation because the game freezes during it.

I've been trying to figure this out for hours. I've googled everything I could think of and have yet to find an answer.

I am a little concerned it might be because my symbol has a large number of frames... it is 850 frames.

Can anyone shed some light on this for me?

Here is the relevant code. This is run in response to a keyboard action by the user:

```
//the nearest frame to jump to in FRONT of the current frame, when something is succesfully eaten.
var nearest_clear_frame:int = 1; 
var curr_frame = water_background.currentFrame;
var i;
var skipped_frames:int = 0;
for(i = 0; i < clear_frames.length -1; i++) {


        var new_delta = (clear_frames[i]-curr_frame);
        var old_delta = (nearest_clear_frame-curr_frame);

        if((new_delta<old_delta || old_delta<0)&& new_delta >= 1){

            nearest_clear_frame = clear_frames[i];
            skipped_frames = nearest_clear_frame -curr_frame;

        }

}

water_background.gotoAndPlay(nearest_clear_frame);
```

`water_background` is the movieClip of the water background t hat is about a 30 second looping video.

`clear_frames` is defined like so:

```
public var clear_frames:Array = [1, 109, 272, 413, 529, 690, 830];
```

`clear_frames` is defined in a separate class, but the class that the main code is in is an extension of that separate class, so I believe I should have full access to it

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

**EDIT**

---

`gotoAndPlay(1)` functions perfectly smooth, but some of the other frames don't, even if I type them in manually instead of using the array.

Here is the size report for the thing:

```
turtle_game.swf Movie Report
-----------------------------

Metadata
--------
Bytes    Value
-----    -----
 1290    <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"> <rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:xmp="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/"> <xmp:CreatorTool>Adobe Flash CS4 Professional</xmp:CreatorTool> <xmp:CreateDate>2011-11-14T14:28:55-08:00</xmp:CreateDate> <xmp:MetadataDate>2011-12-31T12:34:19-08:00</xmp:MetadataDate> <xmp:ModifyDate>2011-12-31T12:34:19-08:00</xmp:ModifyDate> </rdf:Description> <rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:xmpMM="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/mm/" xmlns:stRef="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/sType/ResourceRef#"> <xmpMM:InstanceID>xmp.iid:DCA89ABBEE33E1119D5DF3032563A207</xmpMM:InstanceID> <xmpMM:DocumentID>xmp.did:DCA89ABBEE33E1119D5DF3032563A207</xmpMM:DocumentID> <xmpMM:OriginalDocumentID>xmp.did:2F1CC129100FE111B280DE374C2F22D4</xmpMM:OriginalDocumentID> <xmpMM:DerivedFrom rdf:parseType="Resource"> <stRef:instanceID>xmp.iid:B51A6ED0190FE111B280DE374C2F22D4</stRef:instanceID> <stRef:documentID>xmp.did:B51A6ED0190FE111B280DE374C2F22D4</stRef:documentID> <stRef:originalDocumentID>xmp.did:2F1CC129100FE111B280DE374C2F22D4</stRef:originalDocumentID> </xmpMM:DerivedFrom> </rdf:Description> <rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"> <dc:format>application/x-shockwave-flash</dc:format> </rdf:Description> </rdf:RDF> 

Frame #    Frame Bytes    Total Bytes    Scene
-------    -----------    -----------    ----------------
      1        7792727        7792727    Scene 1 (AS 3.0 Classes Export Frame)
      2              2        7792729    
      3              2        7792731    
      4              2        7792733    
      5              2        7792735    
      6              2        7792737    

      ... i checked all of these and they are roughly identical ...

    837              2        7794399    
    838              2        7794401    
    839              2        7794403    
    840              2        7794405    

Scene                        Shape Bytes    Text Bytes    ActionScript Bytes
-------------------------    -----------    ----------    ------------------
Scene 1                                0             0                 49218

Symbol                       Shape Bytes    Text Bytes    ActionScript Bytes
-------------------------    -----------    ----------    ------------------
water_background2                      0             0                     0
water_background                       0             0                     0
background                             0             0                     0
gauge                                  0             0                     0
stage_mask                             0             0                     0
lose_screen                            0            68                     0
win_screen                             0            66                     0
gauge_mask                            38             0                     0
gauge                                  0             0                     0
gauge_shell                            0             0                     0
main_turtle2                           0             0                     0
Floating Turtle Frames 2               0             0                     0
Floating Turtle Frames                 0             0                     0
Floating Turtle Tweens                 0             0                     0
Floating Turtle Frames3                0             0                     0
item                                   0             0                     0
blf                                    0             0                     0
brf                                    0             0                     0
tlf                                    0             0                     0
trf                                    0             0                     0
body                                   0             0                     0
Tween 1                                0             0                     0
Tween 2                                0             0                     0
main_turtle                            0             0                     0

Font Name                 Bytes        Characters    
----------------------    ---------    --------------
TimesNewRomanPSMT              1633     !LWYnostu

ActionScript Bytes    Location
------------------    --------
             49218    Scene 1:Frame 1

Bitmap                     Compressed    Compression
-----------------------    ----------  --------  -----------
jelly.png                       4546      133056   JPEG Quality=80
bag.png                         6289      176148   JPEG Quality=80
6pack.png                       4730       57936   JPEG Quality=80
turtle.png                     40215     2743296   JPEG Quality=80
back left flipper               3524       56144   JPEG Quality=80
back right flipper              4664       63448   JPEG Quality=80
top left flipper                6228      123300   JPEG Quality=80
top right flipper               4407       69552   JPEG Quality=80
body                           18132      242740   JPEG Quality=80
Gauge-shell.png                10399      236160   JPEG Quality=80
portal.png                    215640     8294400   JPEG Quality=80
Outside Template              140809     7542720   JPEG Quality=80
Finish                          3510       39432   JPEG Quality=80
Start                           3303       39008   JPEG Quality=80
Shark A                         6454      115320   JPEG Quality=80
Shark B                         6360       96672   JPEG Quality=80
Shark C                         6275       96672   JPEG Quality=80
Red Boat                       10781      226872   JPEG Quality=80
Green Boat                     11601      241664   JPEG Quality=80
Yellow Boat                    12305      245504   JPEG Quality=80
Green Leatherback               3755       38352   JPEG Quality=80
Globe                         248169     5607360   JPEG Quality=80
Shadow                        507039     8294400   JPEG Quality=80
Dimpled Aluminum              489466     8294400   JPEG Quality=80
progress_meter.jpg             17398      558112   Imported JPEG=102

Video                       Compressed
------------------------    ----------
background.flv                  5933617
```

Comment: 850 frames for your water? Is it an embedded video, or 850 images? What size (dimensions) is it? Are you doing something like setting `cacheAsBitmap`? It sounds like a memory problem - the 700ms pause is probably the GC kicking in. Can you profile your app, showing the current memory usage? I'm guessing that when you try to play your water anim, there's a big call for memory, which kicks in the GC, which makes your app pause.

Comment: the animation is already running the whole time, I'm just trying to skip forward to the nearest point where the water is at a certain state.   It is an imported .FLV that was made in aftereffects, converted to a symbol.

Comment: i put the size report in the OP

Comment: i'm assuming the imported flv is placed on the timeline and you're controlling it as a movieclip? can you try a use something like `FLVPlayback`: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/video/FLVPlayback.html and use the `seek()` behaviour instead? it might be a problem with embedded flvs

Comment: is there a way to convert the video to just a symbol made of 850 frames, instead of an flv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like anything in your code is a problem.  It sounds like you have some pretty heavy imagery getting loaded on some frames, or else there is some actionscript that is creating objects on certain frames.  It is difficult to share the FLA, but is there an online example that you can show?

Regardless, if you have not already done this, in "Publish Settings", check the box "Generate Size Report".  This option produces an text file in the same directory as your FLA (or as the SWF, maybe?).  There is a wealth of data in that report, and it breaks down frames, objects, time, etc.

Also, don't declare variables in the for-loop.  Also, give all your variables a type.  This is just good practice.

---

EDIT:
Ok, looking at the report, you have a *huge* load (7792727 bytes) in frame 1, and nothing in the others.  This looks mostly like the `background.flv` video, as well as a bunch of other PNG images.  You can try to reduce the size of the PNGs, but I think the big culprit is the FLV video.  You are probably seeking within and SWF to seek within an FLV.  This should be a quick process, but you might try removing the FLV for testing.

If this is not the solution, then you might want to re-check the embedding on `progress_meter.jpg`.

Beyond that, I would have to see the AS3 code.  What you are looking for is object instantiation, object removals, and remote loading of objects (URLLoader, etc.).  Those will be the biggest time consumers.

---

Edit:  I think I would have to see the file to understand it.  You can email to a garbage account I created: testdee@yahoo.com.

Comment: thanks, I typically do those things correctly but after 6 hours of working on this or however long it had been, I started getting sloppier.   I will do the size report soon.

Comment: i put the size report in the OP

Comment: what if I emailed you the AS3?

Comment: Sure.  (Not sure how to do that, though, as I am not inclined to post my email publicly.)

Comment: How would I check if removing the FLV fixes it, when skipping to a certain frame in the FLV is what I need to do? IE, if I remove the video, then I can't see if the problem is there or not, as the problem is with the using `gotoAndPlay(xxx);` on the video.

Comment: Sorry -- I meant type Yahoo.com, but my fingers typed gmail.com.  Ok, try again.